# Get post by two meta key but order by one of them

Tags: posts, meta-query

i'm using this code for getting posts by two meta keys and order posts by on of them but results not true! and not ordered by post views, please help.tnx

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'post_type' => array(
            'key'     => 'file_post_type',
            'value'   => 'software',
        ),
        'post_views' => array(
            'key'     => 'post_views_count',
        ),
        ),
        'orderby' => array( 
        'post_views' => 'DESC',
        ),
        'date_query' => array(
        array(
        'after' => '1 month ago'
        )
        ),
        'numberposts'  =>  $number,
        'cache_results' => false,
        'fields' => 'ids'
        );
        $mview = get_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'meta_key' => 'post_views',
'order' => 'DESC',
```

instead of

```
'orderby' => array( 
        'post_views' => 'DESC',
        ),
```

your way is okay for string, but when you use number it is better to use meta_value_num

meta_value will sort number weird 1, 3, 34, 4, 56, 6, etc, rather than 1, 3, 4, 6, 34, 56 as you might naturally expect as [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) explain

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?